# XSD: how to redefine tags of base schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have to handle multiple XML schemas in order to validate different XML files in a C# application. All these XML schemas share some basic elements, which would be nice to have in a common place without redefining them every time.

My idea is to create a `BaseSchema.xsd` file defining these common elements, and other `SpecificSchema#.xsd` ones defining the specific case-related elements. In these `SpecificSchema#.xsd` schemas I need to use some elements of the base schema, but also to redefine the root tag.

This is an example of what I need:

**BaseSchema.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="BaseSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
  <xs:element name="myRootTag" type="myRootTag" />

  <xs:complexType name="myRootTag">
    <!-- some content -->
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="someCommonTag">
    <!-- some content -->
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**SpecificSchema1.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SpecificSchema1"
           targetNamespace="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:include schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd"/>
  
  <xs:redefine schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="myRootTag">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="myRootTag">
          <!-- some content -->
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:redefine>

  <xs:complexType name="someCustomTag">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- some content -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**SpecificSchema2.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SpecificSchema2"
           targetNamespace="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:include schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd"/>
  
  <xs:redefine schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="myRootTag">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="myRootTag">
          <!-- some other content different from SpecificSchema1.xsd -->
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:redefine>

  <xs:complexType name="someOtherCustomTag">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- some content -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML files I need to validate will be something like this (they will **never** reference `BaseSchema.xsd`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<myRootTag xmlns="http://company.com/myBaseSchema"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://company.com/myBaseSchema SpecificSchema1.xsd">
  <!-- some content -->
</myRootTag>
```

Apparently this seems working (all the schemas are in the same directory and they all reference the same `targetNamespace`), but when I try to load all the schemas in a `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet` it throws this exception:

```
'SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if <redefine> contains any child other than <annotation>.
```

I tried also to reference the full path of `BaseSchema.xsd` in the overriding schemas, but it didn't work.

This is my C# code for schemas loading:

```cs
private XmlSchemaSet LoadSchemas()
{
    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();

    foreach (var schemaPath in Directory.GetFiles(schemasDirectory))
    {
        var schema = LoadSchema(schemaPath);
        schemaSet.Add(schema);
    }

    return schemaSet;
}

private XmlSchema LoadSchema(string uri)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
    {
        return XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit**: I tried also to define the root tag only in the `SpecificSchema#.xsd` schemas and not in the base one, so that no redefine is needed, but I get this error when I create the reader to validate my XML:

```
The global element 'http://company.com/myBaseSchema:myRootTag' has already been declared.
```

Comment: You may want an include statement : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp

Comment: @jdweng I already have `<xs:include schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd"/>`. Is it ok to write just the name of my XSD base file? (All the schemas are in the same folder)

Comment: Usually you put the include in a root schema to include child schemas.  Your c# code will reference the root schema and the children would be found using the include in the root.

Comment: @jdweng so in my `BaseSchema.xsd` I should put the includes for my derived schemas `SpecificSchema#.xsd` and then just leave the redefine in `SpecificSchemas#.xsd` ones? It seems not working, it says "The 'redefine' element cannot appear at this location" when I load a `SpecificSchema#.xsd` schema.

Comment: Schema a generate by orgainzations to standardarize data transfer like the Reality Industry and often contain User Defined Types in the Main Schema.  Users are suppose to Edit the main schema to Add a new type in place of the User Defined Type.  Add an Include statement to the Main Schema.  Then create a new schema for the User Type.  This minimizes the changes that a user needs to do when a new version of the schema is released.

Comment: @jdweng and isn't this what I originally did in the question? I have my `BaseSchema.xsd` (that is your "main schema") and my `SpecificSchema.xsd` (your "user defined schemas") that need to reference the "main" one, but it doesn't work

Comment: The child schema namespaces do not need to reference the base schema.  You end up with a circular reference where the parent references the child and the child references the parent.

Comment: @jdweng but you just said "Add an Include statement **TO** the Main Schema" (I suppose in the child ones), not "**IN** the main schema", and as I said if I put the include **IN** the main schema referencing the child ones it doesn't work... I thought it worked similarly to the include statements in normal code. I can't understand what you mean: can you please give me a complete example in the answers?

Comment: Simple.  The child schema should not reference the parent schema.  It is ok to reference standard schemas the define types like string, and int (for example : xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">).  But not use targetNamespace="http://company.com/myBaseSchema" in the child nor have an include in the child. It is a tree structure and the include is a pointer to the child.  The child does not need to have a pointer to the parent.

Comment: @jdweng but what if, as in this case, I want a child schema to extend/override and use something in the base one? `<redefine>` specified in the child schema needs a reference to the base schema.
My purpose is to avoid XSD definition replication, and have a central point for common stuff.

Comment: I've never uses the override.  I said there are user defined types and have modified the user defines. If you are overriding then it is not necessary to reference the main schema.  It is a tree structure and the compiler will handle the override when it see it.  Do you get an error with the override if the child schema doesn't reference the parent.? I do not think so.  You are getting the error due to the circular referencing.

Comment: @jdweng at the beginning there was no circular reference, since the base schema did not reference any other schema. Now I fixed the `'SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if <redefine> contains any child other than <annotation>.` error, as in the answer I posted: include tags were not the problem (actually, no include was needed at all when using redefine).

Comment: Are you still have issue?  The annotation is the root of the child schema (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_annotation.asp?force_isolation=true).  The error says : 'SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if <redefine> contains any child other than <annotation>.  Looks like one solution is only have the redefine in the child schema and nothing else.

Comment: @jdweng look at the answer I posted: I fixed everything just specifying that XmlUrlResolver in the schema set and loading only the schema I need (which is something I can know at loading time). There are no `<xs:include>` now, in any file, but if I add them again in the child schemas it works anyway. It seems working, thank you for the support.

Comment: @jdweng I tried also to add the `<xs:include>` in the base schema referencing all the child ones, but I have some issues (e.g. VS tooltip says that "multiple redefines of the same schema will be ignored", in fact validation always fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the `'SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if <redefine> contains any child other than <annotation>.` issue just using a `System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver` in the schemaset, changing my loading logic in this way:

```cs
private XmlSchemaSet LoadSchemas()
{
    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.XmlResolver = new System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver();    // this was my missing line

    foreach (var schemaPath in Directory.GetFiles(schemasDirectory))
    {
        var schema = LoadSchema(schemaPath);
        schemaSet.Add(schema);
    }

    return schemaSet;
}

private XmlSchema LoadSchema(string uri)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
    {
        return XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
    }
}
```

But loading all the schemas (base and all `SpecificSchema#.xsd` ones) all together gave me another error:

```
The complexType 'http://company.com/BaseSchema:myRootTag' has already been declared.
```

Therefore, since I know exactly which `SpecificSchema#.xsd` has to be used, I changed again the loading logic loading only the needed one:

```cs
private static XmlSchemaSet LoadSchemaSet()
{
    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.XmlResolver = new System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver();

    var schemaPath = schemasDirectory + "\\SpecifiSchema1.xsd";
    var schema = LoadSchema(schemaPath);
    schemaSet.Add(schema);

    return schemaSet;
}
```

I also removed the `<xs:include>` tags in `SpecificSchema#.xsd` schemas, but in this case it didn't make any difference (`<xs:redefine>` and all the other usage of `BaseSchema.xsd` elements work both with and without it).